Не меняется текст с помощью JS
Подскажите, есть сайт https://academy.otruda.ru/
В шапке сайта ссылки: |Все курсы|Мое обучение|Сотрудники|Отчеты|Паспорт навыков|и т.д.
Пишу скрипт в Tampermonkey.
Как можно поменять текст ссылки в шапке или title или хоть какой то текст на странице?
Код страницы:
*{"title":"Мое обучение","uri":"/mystudy","alias":null,"type":"Menu","eventIsAllowed":false},{"title":"Сотрудники","uri":"/staff","alias":null,"type":"Menu","eventIsAllowed":false},{"title":"Отчеты","uri":"/reports/","alias":null,"type":"Menu"*

Пробовал через: document.querySelector("title").innerText = "Мое обучение2"
Пробовал через:
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('title.Text');
elements.forEach((element) => {
element.textContent = element.textContent.replace('Мое обучение', 'Мое обучение2');
});

Пробовал через: document.querySelector('.noopener noreferrer').textContent = 'Все курсы2';
Никакой реакции на сайте при обновлении, чистил куки, обновлял сайт, ничего не меняется. Настройки скрипта Tampermonkey по умолчанию. В // @match        https://academy.otruda.ru/*
